# tANS Mininum Size of State Set to Safely Encode a Symbol Frame

Tags: compression, language-agnostic

Hi I'm trying to implement tANS in a compute shader, but I am confused about the size of the state set. Also apologies but my account is too new to embed pictures of latex formatted equations.

Imagine we have a symbol frame S comprised of symbols s₁ to sₙ:

S = {s₁, s₂, s₁, s₂, ..., sₙ}

|S| = 2ᵏ

and the probability of each symbol is

pₛₙ = frequency(sₙ) / |S|

∑ pₛ₁ + pₛ₂ + ... pₛₙ = 1

According to Jarek Duda's slides ([which can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyijj8o5jnv48xl/ANSbasic.pdf)) the first step in constructing the encoding function is to calculate the number of states L:

L = |S|

so that we can create a set of states

= {L, ..., 2L - 1}

from which we can construct the encoding table from. In our example, this is simple L = |S| = 2^k. However, we don't want L to necessarily equal |S| because |S| could be enormous, and constructing an encoding table corresponding to size |S| would be counterproductive to compression. Jarek's solution is to create a quantization function so that we can choose an

L : L < |S|

which approximates the symbol probabilities

Lₛ / L ≈ pₛₙ

However as L decreases, the quality of the compression decreases, so I have two questions:

1. How small can we make L while still achieving compression?
2. What is a "good" way of determining the size of L for a given |S|?

In Jarek's [ANS toolkit](https://github.com/JarekDuda/AsymmetricNumeralSystemsToolkit) he uses the depth of a Huffman tree created from S to get the size of L, but this seems like a lot of work when we already know the upper bound of L (|S|; as I understand it when L = |S| we are at the Shannon entropy; thus making L > |S| would not increase compression). Instead it seems like it would be faster to choose an L that is both less than |S| and above some minimum L. A "good" size of L therefore would achieve some amount of compression, but more importantly would be easy to calculate. However we would need to determine the minimum L. Based on the pictures of sample ANS tables it seems like the minimum size of L could be the frequency of the most probable symbol, but I don't know enough about ANS to confirm this.

Comment: Please read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mulling it over for awhile, both questions have very simple answers. The smallest L that still achieves lossless compression is L = |A|, where A is the alphabet of symbols to be encoded(I apologize, the lossless criterion should have been included in the original question). If L < |A| then we are pigeonholing symbols, thus losing information. When L = |A| what we essentially have is a fixed length variable code, where each symbol has an equal probability weighting in our encoding table. The answer to the second part is even more simple now that we know the answer to the first question. L can be pretty much whatever you want so long as its greater than the size of the alphabet to be encoded. Usually we want L to be a power of two for computational efficiency and then we want L to be greater than |A| to achieve better compression, so a very common L size is 2 times the greatest power of two equal to or greater than the size of the alphabet. This can easily be found by something like this:

```
int alphabetSize = SizeOfAlphabet();
int L = pow(2, ceil(log(alphabetSize, 2)) + 1);
```